# Find a load on my Web Server

Tags: performance, web-server, performance-monitoring, performance-tuning, web-applications

As requested, I am asking the [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/296705/find-a-load-on-my-web-server) here.

Is there a way to find a load on my web application server without a load / stress testing?

I have deployed my application in the Apache Tomcat server. As per as I know, each web server have some limitations on serving a request, beyond which, performance degrades. e.g. If a server can handle 800 requests happily, concurrently, the more requests landing on the server will get delayed response, or may be dropped.

I am looking for some alerting mechanism by which I will get to know that the load on my web server has crossed the threshold limit, and accordingly I will able to take the required actions like e.g. adding one more node behind load balancer to distribute the load.

Comment: Please also read the linked references in the above. The people who sent you here asked you to add more detail which you have not. They were also misguided in sending you here.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat will accept as many connections as you configure it to. You can read more about the maxConnections attribute on the Tomcat documentation here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html. There will also be some limitation based on what your current hardware can handle.